# PowerBI - Selecting the Source File(XLSX) dynamically

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to pick up the source file for PowerBI dynamically.

Lets say I have a folder called as Productivity and inside that for every 2 hours a new file is saved out.

I would want the most recent file based on the file name.

```
Productivity-

Prod dec 21 - 1
Prod dec 21 - 2
prod dec 21 - 3
```

I want PowerBI to select the most recent one which is `prod dec 21 - 3` and is it possible to show the file name on the report, so that they know how updated the data is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to load a folder in the query editor. It will load a list of data files within that folder.

Sort rows by Date modified (descending), then choose Keep Rows > Keep Top Rows and set the number of rows to keep as 1.

Finally, click on the double down arrow on the Content column to drill down and return whichever table you are wanting to load.